# How to render jsx based on condition using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have code like below,

```
const ParentComponent = ({data}: {data: Array<DataType>}) => {
    const version = data.version; //version is an array
    const type = data.type; //type is an object
    const renderContent = () => {
        return (
            <Flex flexDirection="column">
                <div>version</div> //this to be displayed if version not empty
                <div>{version}</div> // this to be displayed if version is not empty
                <div>type</div> //this to be shown if type has name or version
                <div>{type.name} {type.number}</div> //this to be shown if type has 
                // name or version 
            </Flex>
        ); 
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Flex>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" /> 
                </div>
            </Flex>
            <Icon name="help" /> //this to be displayed only when version is not 
            //empty array or type has name or number
        </>
    );
}
```

the above code works fine. but i want to display Icon only when version is not empty array or type has name or number

and within rendercontent div with version should be shown if version not empty and div with type to be shown if type has name or version.

how can i do it could someone help me with this. i am new to programming and learning on the go. thanks.

Comment: Use conditional rendering. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by conditionally rendering

```
const ParentComponent = ({data}: {data: Array<DataType>}) => {
    const version = data.version; //version is an array
    const type = data.type; //type is an object
    const renderContent = () => {
        return (
            <Flex flexDirection="column">
                {version && version.length ?  (
                    <>
                      <div>version</div> //this to be displayed if version not empty
                      <div>{version}</div> // this to be displayed if version is not empty
                    </>
                 ) : null}
                  {(type.version || type.name) ? (
                     <>
                     <div>type</div> //this to be shown if type has name or version
                     <div>{type.name} {type.number}</div> //this to be shown if type has 
                // name or version 
                    </>
                  ) : null}
          
            </Flex>
        ); 
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Flex>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" /> 
                </div>
            </Flex>
             {version && version.length ? (
               <Icon name="help" /> //this to be displayed only when version is not 
            //empty array or type has name or number
             )}
            
        </>
    );
}
```